# Rookie trying to create php template engine

Tags: php, templates

```html
<?php

//The below is for testing only - no longer required
$contentExample = array(
 array(
  "name" => "First Product",
  "price" => "€24.99",
  "description" => "This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 ),
 array(
  "name" => "Second Product",
  "price" => "€64.99",
  "description" => "This is another description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 ),
 array(
  "name" => "Third Product",
  "price" => "€74.99",
  "description" => "This is another description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 ),
 array(
  "name" => "Fourth Product",
  "price" => "$19.99",
  "description" => "This is another description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 ),
 array(
  "name" => "Fifth Product",
  "price" => "€12.99",
  "description" => "This is another description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 ),
 array(
  "name" => "Sixth Product",
  "price" => "€84.99",
  "description" => "This is another description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 )
);

class Template{
 private $template;
 private $content = array();
 private $hasNext;
 private $noOfResults;

 public function __construct($template,$content){
  //Should validate arguments before we continue
  $this->load($template,$content);
 }


 public function __GET($val){
  if($val=="hasNext"){
   return $this->$val;
  }
  else if($val !== "noOfResults"){
   return $this->$val;
  }
  else{
   die("Cannot access private property Template::$val");
  }
 }
 public function output(){
  if($this->hasNext){
   $record = current($this->content);
   $html = $this->template;

   //test case: $key = "name", $val = "First Product"

   foreach($record as $key=>$val){
    $html = str_replace('{'.$key.'}',$val,$html);
   }
   if(!next($this->content)){
    $this->hasNext = FALSE;
   }
   return $html;
  }
  else{
   return "";
  }
 }

 public function load($template,$content){
  $this->template = file_get_contents("templates/$template",true);
  //$this->template = $template;
  $this->content = $content;
  $this->hasNext = TRUE;
  $this->noOfResults = sizeof($this->content);
  if($this->noOfResults == 0){
   $this->hasNext = FALSE;
  }
 }
}

/*$test = new Template("product_thumbnail.html",$contentExample);

while($test->hasNext){
echo $test->output();
}*/
```

The reason I am trying to build rather than use an pre-existing temp engine is so i can see how it works. Whats the point of just using code i don't understand??

i end up getting this error

Notice: Undefined variable: content in C:\xampp\htdocs\Shawpify\Shawpify\ShawpifyV5.0\index.php on line 124
Cannot access private property Template::noOfRresults

code causing this is:

```
public function __GET($val){
    if($val=="hasNext"){
        return $this->$val;
    }
    else if($val =="noOfResults"){
        return $this->$val;
    }
    else{
        die("Cannot access private property Template::$val");
    }
}
```

I have checked for spelling errors, all files do exits, checked for sytax errors but training

Thanx in advance for any advice or soloutions

Comment: `"noOfRresults" !== "noOfResults"`

Comment: This error means that `val` has a value other than the ones that you have written. Post the rest of your code if you want help.

Comment: Also, you error message is misleading, since it will be displayed for any random (eg non existent) property

Comment: Still says undefined variable

Comment: just added the code

Comment: To elaborate on my comment, your error message suggests you have a spelling mistake - both a lower case and uppercase letter R.

Comment: Good day steve just checked no spelling mistakes allover written the same

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is trying to access the property anyway because it is between double quotes (`"`).
Put the error message in single quotes so it doesn't get parsed.

```
die('Cannot access private property Template::$val');
```

Answer (score 0):

FOR FUTURE REFERENCE

i found the error and have fixed the error that where syntax errors and naming errors here is the correct answers

```html
<?php

//The below is for testing only - no longer required
$contentExample = array(
 array(
  "name" => "First Product",
  "price" => "€24.99",
  "description" => "This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 ),
 array(
  "name" => "Second Product",
  "price" => "€64.99",
  "description" => "This is another description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 ),
 array(
  "name" => "Third Product",
  "price" => "€74.99",
  "description" => "This is another description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 ),
 array(
  "name" => "Fourth Product",
  "price" => "$19.99",
  "description" => "This is another description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 ),
 array(
  "name" => "Fifth Product",
  "price" => "€12.99",
  "description" => "This is another description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 ),
 array(
  "name" => "Sixth Product",
  "price" => "€84.99",
  "description" => "This is another description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 )
);

class Template{
 private $template;
 private $content;
 private $hasNext;
 private $noOfResults;

 public function __construct($template,$content){
  //Should validate arguments before we continue
  $this->load($template,$content);
 }

 public function __get($val){
  if($val=="hasNext"){
   return $this->$val;
  }
  else if($val=="noOfResults"){
   return $this->$val;
  }
  else{
   die("Cannot access private property Template::$val");
  }
 }
 public function output(){
  $record= current($this->content);
        $html =$this->template;

        foreach($record as $key=>$val){
            $html = str_replace("{".$key."}",$val, $html);
        }
        if(!next($this->content)){
            $this->hasNext=FALSE;
        }
        return $html;
 }

 public function load($template,$content){
  $this->template = file_get_contents("http://localhost/Shawpify/ShawpifyV5.0/templates/$template",true);
  //$this->template = $template;
  $this->content = $content;
  $this->hasNext = TRUE;
  $this->noOfResults = sizeof($this->content);
  
 }
}
/*$test = new Template("product_thumbnail.html",$contentExample);

while($test->hasNext){
    echo $test->output();
}*/
```